# How to save page Filter state in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, filtering

I have website asp.net MVC 5 application, I have a question about best practices using a filter in the page

What's the issue:

I have an Employer page that has a filter (id, name, status, page (using PageList)) EmployerController
And Employee page that has a filter of (id, name, status, page (using PageList)) EmployeeController

every employer has employees and the issues are to save employer filter when I getting back from an employee to employer contoller

For Example:
in Employer page 4 I clicked on employer 123 and it's gone to employees page that relevant to him when I went back to the employer's page (i have a button for that) isn't refreshing the page and go to employer page 1 instead of 4

What I do

I starting to pass parameters for an employer to an employee that will pass back when I click on the go back button but it's a lot of passing because employers have a page to so on every page I need to pass params/object

is there any best practices for that kind of problem for storing the filter from one controller when i calling another or its all custom made

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think about a good idea of using Session for that case

it will be a couple of const that will be used in sessions

```
public static class Sessions {
public static const string Page = "Page";
}
```

in the view i will set the value

```
Session[Sessions.Page] = this.page;
```

and if i click on the return button i will be getting to the function BackFromView that will be in the controller

that function will init filter from the session and redirect it to the index page.